# Mapping pandas df to JSON Schema

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is my df:

|  | text | date | channel | sentiment | product | segment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | I like the new layout | 2021-08-30T18:15:22Z | Snowflake | predict | Skills | EMEA |

I need to convert this to JSON output that matches the following:

```
[
  {
    "text": "I like the new layout",
    "date": "2021-08-30T18:15:22Z",
    "channel": "Snowflake",
    "sentiment": "predict",
    "fields": [
      {
        "field": "product",
        "value": "Skills"
      },
      {
        "field": "segment",
        "value": "EMEA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm getting stuck with mapping the keys of the columns to the values in the first dict and mapping the column and row to new keys in the final dict. I've tried various options using `df.groupby` with `.apply()` but am coming up short.

Samples of what I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['text', 'date','channel','sentiment','product','segment']).apply(
     lambda r: r[['27cf2f]].to_dict(orient='records')).unstack('text').apply(lambda s: [
{s.index.name: idx, 'fields': value}
for idx, value in s.items()]
).to_json(orient='records')
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: I believe your given df has some column missing. Also you might want to add a line before table or it's not correctly shown.

Comment: @Cookie The df is correct. Thanks for the feedback on the markdown tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a nested list comprehension:

```
# Start with your example data
d = {'text': ['I like the new layout'],
     'date': ['2021-08-30T18:15:22Z'],
     'channel': ['Snowflake'],
     'sentiment': ['predict'],
     'product': ['Skills'],
     'segment': ['EMEA']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Specify field column names
fieldcols = ['product', 'segment']

# Build a dict for each group as a Series named `fields`
res = (df.groupby(['text', 'date','channel','sentiment'])
 .apply(lambda s: [{'field': field, 
                    'value': value}
                   for field in fieldcols
                   for value in s[field].values])
).rename('fields')

# Convert Series to DataFrame and then to_json
res = res.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')

# Print result
import json
print(json.dumps(json.loads(res), indent=2))

[
  {
    "text": "I like the new layout",
    "date": "2021-08-30T18:15:22Z",
    "channel": "Snowflake",
    "sentiment": "predict",
    "fields": [
      {
        "field": "product",
        "value": "Skills"
      },
      {
        "field": "segment",
        "value": "EMEA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! This works perfectly. Marked as accepted!

As a follow on, how would you do this if you had multiple columns you needed in the fields array?

Comment: Thanks Matthew! Do you mean how to extend this to work on multiple additional columns with names like `27cf2f`? I would try something like a second list or dict comprehension to loop over the field-id columns, or maybe a `pd.melt` first to move the field ids from column names into a single column, and the field values into their own column.

Comment: Hey Peter. Yes that's correct. I've updated the question to reflect the needed logic as I'm struggling to get the code worked out for the addtional columns. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. I've edited my answer to work on multiple field columns. Hopefully that works!